# F# Monad multiple parameters

Tags: f#, functional-programming, monads, either

I am trying to wrap my head around monads and how to use them in real world examples. The first "task" i set myself is to write an "Exception Monad" which of course (at this point) is nothing more than the "Either monad" twisted to suit my purpose.

My code looks like this:

```
type MException<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

    with
    static member returnM a =
        Success a

    static member bind f =
        fun e ->
            match e with
            | Success a -> f a
            | Failure m -> Failure m

    static member map f =
        fun e ->
            match e with
            | Success a -> Success (f a)
            | Failure m -> Failure m

// Create a little test case to test my code
let divide (n, m) =
    match m with
    | 0 -> Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
    | _ -> Success ((float n) / (float m))

let round (f:float) =
    Success ( System.Math.Round(f, 3) )

let toString (f:float) =
    sprintf "%f" f

let divideRoundAndPrintNumber = 
    divide
    >> MException<_>.bind round 
    >> MException<_>.map toString

// write the result
let result = divideRoundAndPrintNumber (11, 3)
match result with
| Success r -> printf "%s\n" r
| Failure m -> printf "%s\n" m
```

My question is the following: the divide function now takes a tuple. What can or should I do to make the bind and map functions behave correctly for functions with multiple parameters?

EDIT 30-12-2015:
Both the answers and comments of @Mark Seemann helped find the answer to the problem. @Mikhail provided the implementation of the solution. Currying is the right way of solving the problem. Computation Expressions are not a solution but a syntax abstraction which does work but gets complicated once you add async and other patterns to the problem. "Simple" composition seems like the easiest and "trueest" solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `divideRoundAndPrintNumber` to be a function instead of a value

```
let divide n m =
    match m with
    | 0 -> Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
    | _ -> Success ((float n) / (float m))

let divideRoundAndPrintNumber n = 
    divide n
    >> MException<_>.bind round
    >> MException<_>.map toString
```

Comment: Thank you, currying is indeed the only viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not know enough about F# to understand your code completely. For example I do not understand the >> operator and the MException<_> expression. But I can give you an alternative solution for your problem. It utilzies a F# feature called "Computation Expressions". It enables you to do "Monadic" magic in a nice F#-like way:

```
type MException<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

type ExceptionBuilder() =

    member this.Bind (m, f) =
        match m with
        | Success a -> f a
        | Failure m -> Failure m

    member this.Return (x) =
        Success (x)

let ex = new ExceptionBuilder()

let divide n m =
    if m = 0 then Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
             else Success ((float n)/(float m))

let round (f : float) =
    Success (System.Math.Round(f, 3))

let divideRoundAndPrintNumber a b =
    ex {
        let! c = divide a b
        let! d = round c
        printf "result of divideRoundAndPrintNumber: %f\n" d
        return d
    }

let result = divideRoundAndPrintNumber 11 0
match result with
| Success r -> printf "%f\n" r
| Failure m -> printf "%s\n" m
```

Apologies when my answer does not match your question completely but I hope it helps.

Here you can find an excellent blog post series about this topic:

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/

I also found this article very enlightening:

http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have to read the examples and articles before I can verify if it is the correct answer. Two things to note:
1) Yes, for some reason this Bind function of the CE really does "just do the right thing" when it comes to parameters, magic!
2) the >> is called the forward composition operator which composes two functions into another function; the reason for monads (imho) is to get composition and with it reduce complexity. I really need dive into those articles to see if your solution reduces complexity like that. (will edit this comment when I have more information)

Answer (score 2):

Monads have a fairly strict required structure, they must have:

Return: `'a -> m<'a>`

and

Bind: `m<'a> -> ('a -> m<'b>) -> m<'b>`

Your divide function has the signature `int*int -> MException<float>`, i.e. it does indeed have the required `'a -> m<'b>` form to be used with bind.  When used with bind, it would act on something of type `MException<int*int>` and produce an `MException<float>`.

If `divide` is instead of type `int -> int -> MException<float>` (i.e. `'a -> 'b -> m<'c>'`), we can't use it with bind directly.  What we can do is unwrap the tuple and then supply the arguments one by one to create a lambda that does have the right form.

Let's add an extra `Return` so that we can see more clearly some different approaches for handling functions within these constraints:

```
let divideTupled (n, m) =
    match m with
    | 0 -> Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
    | _ -> Success ((float n) / (float m))

let divideRoundAndPrintNumber n m =
    MException<_>.Return (n,m) 
    |> MException<_>.Bind divideTupled
    |> MException<_>.Bind round 
    |> MException<_>.Map toString
```

or

```
let divideCurried n m =
    match m with
    | 0 -> Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
    | _ -> Success ((float n) / (float m))

let divideRoundAndPrintNumber n m =
    MException<_>.Return (n,m) 
    |> MException<_>.Bind (fun (n,m) -> divideCurried n m)
    |> MException<_>.Bind round 
    |> MException<_>.Map toString
```

Computation expressions, as mentioned by Olaf, provide some nice syntactic sugar for working with monads in F#.

Comment: Hi, would something like: 
`M<'a> -> ( 'c -> ('a -> M<'b>)) -> M<'b>`
Make any sense? I'm trying to find a notation to melt the curried form of a function into my `bind` definition.

Comment: @Mr.Baudin To use a curried function inside bind, you'll have to do some kind of function conversion as I showed to make the function into the correct form.  Notice that in the bind function `M<'a> -> ('a -> M<'b>) -> M<'b>` the 'a is supplied by the `M<'a>` but you have no such source for the `'c` parameter.  If you want to use curried args in bind, you'll have to be able to derive them from all from `'a` as in my second example or supply one of the parameters by hand, e.g. `divideCurried 2`

Answer (score 2):

Why not define `divide` like you normally would?

```
let divide n m =
    match m with
    | 0 -> Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
    | _ -> Success ((float n) / (float m))
```

You could then define `divideRoundAndPrintNumber` like this, likewise in curried form:

```
let divideRoundAndPrintNumber n m = 
    divide n m
    |> MException<_>.bind round 
    |> MException<_>.map toString
```

FSI ad-hoc tests:

```
> let result = divideRoundAndPrintNumber 11 3;;    
val result : MException<string> = Success "3.667000"

> let result = divideRoundAndPrintNumber 11 0;;    
val result : MException<string> = Failure "Cannot divide by zero"
```

Comment: This works when I chain the functions but I can't seem to be able to find a composed solution which works. (divide n m) returns a value instead of a function which I can compose and apart from currying my divide function down to one parameter I do not see a solution

Comment: @Mr.Baudin Can you elaborate on what it is that you want to achieve? Ultimately, a `divide` function needs *two* values, and the curried form is the idiomatic F# form, whereas the tupled form isn't. It's true that `divide n m` returns a value, but both `divide` and `divide n` return functions...

Comment: You are right about the divide function. I can solve the problem by doing: int -> (int -> M 'a), so through currying I can reduce the number of parameters needed and supply my composition with a function of the right signature. I as looking for a way to construct my monad in such a way that "number of parameters for composition" wasn't a problem anymore.

Comment: @Mr.Baudin In my experience, it *isn't* a problem... See @Mikhail's answer for a slightly alternative syntax for composing with the curried `divide` function.

Comment: I just had a "oh no" moment. Was doing the math and currying is the only option else the associativity rule no longer applies...sorry for the confusion, again I got hit with the math stick!